# A game with equal devices

Tags: android, andengine, multiplayer

I know this is not exactly a StackOverflow question, but nobody answered it on the AndEngine forum.
I'm trying to develop a 2 player game similar to Connect 4 or Chess. The game would be played between two devices in the same network. Both devices have to be able to receive and send messages (position, winner, ...).

Is this possible with the MultiplayerExtension?
Which is easier or better to use: multiplayer over Wi-Fi or over Bluetooth?
Is there a way for a client to not have to write the IP of the server manually?

Comment: Keep in mind that using Bluetooth can deter users. Even though the power usage has been greatly decreased since Bluetooth 4.0, the old power consumption and the fact that by long not everybody has access to Bluetooth 4.0, will deter users. So using WiFi surely seems the best option.

Comment: Yes, its possible using the multiplayer extension but IP discovery will be a problem for the players. Another approach is through AppWarp which will allow you to do matchmaking easily and also exchange messages between the client apps. Here is code project link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611201/Make-realtime-multiplayer-AndEngine-games